# Removing a child from a tree

Tags: java, data-structures

If I check if the `children` contains `childToRemove`, why do I need another else for checking if the child is in `this.children`?

```
 public void removeChild(TreeNode childToRemove)
  {
           if(this.children.isEmpty())
           {
             return ;
           }
           else if(this.children.contains(childToRemove))
           {
               this.children.remove(childToRemove);
               return;
           }
           else
           {
             for(TreeNode child : this.children)
             {
                 child.removeChild(childToRemove);
             }
           }
  }
```

Comment: what's the type of `children`? If it's `ArrayList`, you don't need do like this.

Comment: Because this method is doing a recursive removal... that means that the child should be removed even if it's not a direct child, but a child of a child... The first branch (isEmpty) takes care of the trivial case where there are no children. The second (children.contains) takes care of direct children... and the final "else" branch takes care of indirect children (child of child of child....) recursively.

Comment: @Renato , thank you for helping me to understand.

Comment: No problem. @mario you got downvoted because your question lacked context... like: where is this code from, what's the surrounding class, why do you need to know this, what's the type of `children`, etc... to be able to answer properly we would need to know all of that.  I had to guess that `children` is a `List<TreeNode>` and that the class surrounding this method is also of type `TreeNode`, for example. But if those assumptions are wrong, my explanation would be incorrect.

Comment: BTW this method is probably buggy... e.g. can the same child appear in multiple locations? Direct children seem to be removed only once (i.e. if the child appears in multiple different locations ,only one of them is removed) but the recursive removal does not stop after the first found child is removed (it might remove many indirect children). I would return a `boolean` from this method, similar to Java's remove methods, so you can choose to stop after the first child is found and removed (if that's what you need)... if you need to remove from any location, direct removal is wrong.

Comment: As you still need to continue to the recursive removal to get rid of also indirect children.

Comment: If you only want to remove one child, then this method is inefficient because it won't stop recursion once the first child has been removed. It should check a boolean value returned by this method to know when to stop early.

Comment: Please move this question to https://parenting.stackexchange.com/ (sorry, I couldn't resist). :D

Comment: @CostiCiudatu I was going to reply: better call the fire department XD

Answer (score 0):

As I've written in the comments, I am assuming that:

- this method is in the class `TreeNode`.
- `this.children` has type `List<TreeNode>`.

I.e. this is a basic tree data structure.

I will also assume that a child may only appear once in the tree. If it could appear multiple times, this would be a graph, not a tree.

Given these assumptions, this method is buggy and should be written as follows (with comments explaining why):

```java
/**
 * Remove the given node from this TreeNode.
 *
 * @param childToRemove the child to be removed
 * @return true if the child was removed, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean removeChild(TreeNode childToRemove)
{
           // if this tree is empty, there's nothing to do
           if(this.children.isEmpty())
           {
             return false;
           }

           // there's no point checking with "contains", just try
           // to remove the child, and if that succeeds, we're done.
           if (this.children.remove(childToRemove)) 
           {
             return true;
           }

           // the child is not a direct child of this TreeNode, but it
           // may be an indirect child, i.e. a descendant of this node,
           // so we need to try every single descendant in this tree,
           // stopping as soon as we find it to avoid wasting time.
           for(TreeNode child : this.children)
           {
               if (child.removeChild(childToRemove))
               {
                   return true;
               }
           }

           // we couldn't find the node anywhere, so it couldn't be removed.
           return false;
}
```

Also, because this method is removing any descendant, not just direct children (a child is normally only a direct child, right? Indirect children are grand-children, grand-grand-children etc.), I would rename the method to make that more obvious, to something like `removeNode` or `removeDescendant`.